# How to create a RewriteRule to N params?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, friendly-url

Currently I have a site that works with recursive categories, ie, there are endless categories. I can pass as many parameters as ever want by setting a new parameter manually. How do my .htaccess accept N parameters for categories automatically?

Currently I use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ view/index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Search for something like this:

www.mysite.com/cat1/cat2/cat3/cat4/.../product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass full URI to `index.php` and then split it inside the PHP code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ view/index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```